# What team/weapon makeup should I use from Chapter 11 on?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I can't decide on the team I want to go with from chapter 11 and forward.

I hate Hope and Snow so I do not want them in my party.

I love Sazh as a SYN and he's the only cool male character in the story, so I would like to include him and buy him flowers.

Which two ladies should I pick to keep him company?

And once that's decided: what roles and weapons would then be best suited for that party?

Edit:

So... after some more research I think I have decided:

- Fang as COM/SEN/RAV with Taming Pole for COM
- Vanille as MED/SAB/RAV with Healer's Staff for MED (and possibly Belladonna Wand for SAB later on)
- Sazh as SYN/COM/RAV probably with Spica for SYN (but suggestions are welcome)

How's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leader: Fang (anything will do, as long as it is not the stagger lock weapon)

Companion 1: Lightning (I like lifesaber)

Companion 2: Vanille/Hope (Vanille's staff for debuffing (Belladonna Wand or upgrades thereof))

If you really want to use Sazh, then I recommend you replace Lightning for him.

```
Paradigm: Com/rav/rav
          sab/med/sab(or syn)
          com/com/rav
          def(or com)/med/med
Consider: def/def/def
          sab/syn/syn(or sab)
```

You will want to change the team sometimes for missions, but that's another tale. With that team you should be able to emerge victorious (it was my setup when I killed the final boss).

Good luck ;)

Comment: quick note, i reccomend you do use Hope, you''l thank me later ;)

Comment: But Hope is dead to me! Thanks for the reply though, please check my edit :)

Comment: hmm, yea that might work out also ;)

Comment: I also play a lot of Fang/Sazh/Vanille. The trick with this party is the best weapon for both Fang and Sazh has stagger lock, and Vanille spends much of her time as a healer, meaning it can be harder to finish a stagger in the tough fights, when you really need it. You either have to give something up with Fang's weapon or go a completely different direction.